# Zend Navigation routes in xml config not using passed in parameters

Tags: zend-framework, zend-navigation, zend-config-xml

I have a route:

```
resources.router.routes.page.route = "page/:page"
resources.router.routes.page.defaults.module = "core"
resources.router.routes.page.defaults.controller = "page"
resources.router.routes.page.defaults.action = "view"
resources.router.routes.page.defaults.page = "home"
```

Here is my navigation xml:

```
<company>
    <label>Company</label>
    <route>page</route>
    <page>company</page>
</company>
```

As you can see here, Id like to use my route (and use the page variable) within my zend navigation xml. The problem is, the page element isn't being used. The result becomes:

`http://localhost/website/public/page`

instead of

`http://localhost/website/public/page/company`

How can I get zend navigation to use the page parameter?

Thanks!

Comment: I figured it out. You need to wrap the page element within a params element

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to wrap the page element within a params element. See as follows:

```
<company>
    <label>Company</label>
    <route>page</route>
    <params>
       <page>company</page>
    </params>
</company>
```